# File.Move Progress bar

Tags: c#, file-io

I have a program that users are using that will take a file from their system and move it to a network drive in order to be processed and stored. The move itself works fine and everything works properly, unless they are moving a big file and for some reason close the program early and stop the process.

The code I use to move the file is

```
try { File.Move(docFilepath, docFilePathTo); }
catch (Exception ex)
{
    docName = config.autoRename(docName + docExt.ToUpper()).Split('.')[0];
    File.Move(docFilepath, frmMain.Scans2LF + docName + docExt.ToUpper());
}
```

Again this works fine. I was wondering if there was a possibility to have a progress bar to display to the user when their file was actually fully in the new location.

I have looked up a couple questions that have a semi relevance to this but not any answer that would work for my situation. Changing the system for moving the file is not an option for me so i am stuck trying to find a way for progress or completion to be finished.

***Edit***

I can possibly look into changing the way files are moved, main problem would be explaining it so that my boss wouldn't think its a bad idea to change things that work (if people don't close the program.....)

***End Edit***

I thought of using a look-up for the new file in its location and the size is is currently at as a progress meter but not sure if this would work.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: `Changing the system for moving the file is not an option for me` That pretty much rules out any solution that would be worth anything.  Why can't you change how the file is actually moved?

Comment: Well, if we were allowed to give you an answer that would help, I'd suggest using `SHFileOperation` and let the system show its standard UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the Windows file progress dialog just add `Microsoft.VisualBasic` as a reference and use the FileMove from there

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.MoveFile("sorceFile.ext", "destFile.ext", Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs);
```

This will show the same dialog as widnows does, including Cancel options etc if required.

Comment: The OP specifically states that `Changing the system for moving the file is not an option for me`

Comment: @Servy check the edit. "I can possibly look into changing the way files are moved..."

Comment: Quick question for testing this method. Will nothing show up if the file is to small and pretty much instantly is moved?

Comment: Nvm answered my own question with testing. Now new question. Can i disable the cancel button on the progress meter?